# Add native ES6 Promise to Protractor/WebDriverJS ControlFlow in Typescript

Tags: selenium-webdriver, typescript, jasmine, protractor, es6-promise

I'm currently calling some external code in my Protractor tests that returns ES6 Promises.

I was hoping to chain these promises using a ControlFlow, but I get a type error when it compiles the Typescript.

In test:

```
import {browser} from 'protractor';
...
it('should have a title', () => {
  let flow = browser.controlFlow();
  flow.execute(testServer.fixture('user_test_roles'));
});
```

When run:

```
[13:04:39] E/launcher - Error: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript
src/app/app.e2e.ts (9,18): Argument of type 'Promise<{}>' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => {} | Promise<{}>'.
  Type 'Promise<{}>' provides no match for the signature '(): {} | Promise<{}>' (2345)
```

If I try `flow.wait()` I get a different type error:

```
[13:08:27] E/launcher - Error: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript
src/app/app.e2e.ts (9,15): Argument of type 'Promise<{}>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Function | Promise<{}>'.
  Type 'Promise<{}>' is not assignable to type 'webdriver.promise.Promise<{}>'.
    Property 'cancel' is missing in type 'Promise<{}>'. (2345)
```

Is there some way that I can wrap the promises to make them compatible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Control flow is looking for a `ManagedPromise` that is provided from `selenium-webdriver`. This will not work if `testServer.fixture` is returning a native ES6 promise. Native ES6 promises are not the same `webdriver.promise.Promise`

Comment: I guess I'm asking what's the difference between a `ManagedPromise` and native ES6 promise? Is it purely the interface, like ES6 vs. jQuery vs. Angular `$q` promises? Or is there a broader integration or paradigm difference going on? Do they behave differently?

Comment: Might not have included this in the statement above but `ManagedPromise` is exported as `webdriver.promise.Promise` The webdriver promise and native ES6 promises have similar interfaces; however, `ManagedPromise` has additional methods like `cancel` which is why you are getting a type error. Control flow handles your managed promises and executes your promises in order. This is why they have their own implementation. Currently in selenium-webdriver 3.0.0, they are using native promises but they still have a `ManagedPromise`. The current version of selenium-webdriver in Protractor is 2.53.1.